# Can Markdown image links be generated using POD6?

Tags: markdown, raku, pod6

In all of my Raku packages, the README has a line at the top having Travis badge for the module, like this:

```
[![Build Status](https://travis-ci.org/Kaiepi/p6-Failable.svg?branch=master)](https://travis-ci.org/Kaiepi/p6-Failable)
```

At the moment, I am generating the README using POD6 in the main module, but I am manually copying the link to the Travis badge every time I do this. Is there some way to format the link with POD6 so I don't have to?

Comment: Which module are you using for porting Pod to Markdown? Pod::To::Markdown?

Comment: `Pod::To::Markdown`, yes.

Comment: If you're using `perl6 --doc=Markdown myPack.pm6 > README.md `, you should get the the link as is in your `README.md` as shown [here](https://github.com/retupmoca/p6-markdown/blob/master/lib/Text/Markdown.pm6#L46).

Comment: Ah, not sure why I didn't think to try that.

Comment: @uzlxxxx can you please promote that to full answer, so that this question is not unanswered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the Markdown link directly in the Pod and `Pod::To::Markdown` will leave it as is for the Pod to Markdown conversion.

Comment: does it work for badges which are mixture of an image and http link?